# Можно ли оптимизировать внутреннюю процедуру?

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Есть внутренняя процедура (FireBird)

```
begin
  select count(distinct DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE)
      from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL
        where PROPOSAL_ID = :IN_PROPOSAL_ID
          into :VAR1;
  for
    select DEVICE_ID
      from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL
        where PROPOSAL_ID = :IN_PROPOSAL_ID
        and DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE is null
          into :OUT_DEVICE_ID
  do
  begin
    OUT_DEPARTMENT_DIFFERENT = :VAR1;
    suspend;
  end
end
```

в которой первый “*select*” может выдать выборку, а второй “*select*”, может выдать только одну строку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin
  select count(distinct DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE), max(CASE WHEN DEPARTMENT_ID_EXECUTE is null THEN DEVICE_ID END)
      from DISTRIBUTION_PROPOSAL
        where PROPOSAL_ID = :IN_PROPOSAL_ID
          into :OUT_DEPARTMENT_DIFFERENT, :OUT_DEVICE_ID;

  suspend;
end
```